# How to use Objects as parameters in REST webservices

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest, jax-rs

I am writing a rest service looking something like this:

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
public void save(@QueryParam("firstName") String firstName, @QueryParam("lastName") String lastName, @QueryParam("email") String email) {
    User user = new User(firstName, lastName, email);
    db.createUser(user);
}
```

I would like to be able to have something like an object parameter:

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
public void save(@ObjectParam User user) {
    db.createUser(user);
}
```

It would be nice not having to specify what parameters i am expecting or writing my own object parser.

Comment: Have you tried it?  Did you get an error?

Comment: @ObjectParam doesn't exist, but i would like something like that. Right now i don't have a way to use an object as parameter

Comment: See @WestonJones answer - everything you include in the parameter list is seen as message body - annotations are only needed if you want to have further parameters which are present as path or query params.

Answer (score 1):

This should be sufficient

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
public void save(User user) {
    db.createUser(user);
}
```

It should map the object to JSON as long as you include a JSON object in your POST that matches.

Answer (score 0):

In Spring REST, one may do the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Car> update(@RequestBody Car car) {
    ...
}
```